# Why Can't I have Condition Variable Inside IF statement Javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
if (0==0){console.log(true)}
```

**Expected**: true **Result**: true

```
if (0==1){console.log(true)}
```

**Expected**: undefined **Result**: undefined

```
var c = "0==1";
if (c){console.log(true)}
```

**Expected**: undefined **Result**: true

How can I get "undefined" result in the third statement? Just like the second statement.

Comment: `"0==1"` is a string. a non empty string becomes true

Comment: `var c = 0 == 1;` currently `c` is string

Comment: How can I turn "c" into condition?

Comment: Variables and strings do not work like copy and pasting code. A string is not evaluated as code. A string is *truthy*, period.

Comment: @deceze: Actually, the empty string is falsy. (String *objects* are truthy, period, but JavaScript also has string *primitives*.)

Comment: BTW second result is not undefined, it is resulting in false and so no log.

Comment: @ruakh <strike>A</strike> *Your* string is truthy.

Comment: you need to use `eval` function but thats not recommended. You need to reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"0==1" is a valid string

You should rather use

```
var c = 0==1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string `"0==1"` is non empty or null so it will pass the if test

You can use eval function which evaluates your string.

```
var c = "0==1";
if (eval(c)){console.log(true)}
```

Or you can say that `c = 0==1;` but better write `c = false;`, not?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get "undefined" result in the third statement? Just like the second statement.

I don't particularly recommend this, but — you can use `eval`, which parses and evaluates the JavaScript code in its string argument:

```
var c = "0==1";
if (eval(c)){console.log(true)}
```

For more information, see [the 'eval()' page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there are predefined `FALSY` values everything else are `TRUTHY` values. So "0==1" becomes `TRUTHY` value.

**FALSY** values:

- false.
- 0 (zero)
- "" (empty string)
- null.
- undefined.
- NaN (a special Number value meaning Not-a-Number!)

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = "0==1";
if (c){console.log(true)}
```

c now has a value of "0==1" which is a string. If you wanted to get an undefined value you would do the following:

```
//c now has a variable reverence but an undefined (null) value
var c = undefined; 
if (c){console.log(true)}
```

Undefined basically means that the object does not exist. In your case the value c does exist as you have created a string with the text: "0==1".

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Undefined doesn't mean "that the object doesn't exist." In your example `c` very well exists. `undefined` means `undefined`, nothing more, nothing less. Certain expressions will produce an `undefined` value (like accessing a non-existing property of an object), but the `undefined` value is just a value.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but from my understanding the variable exists but the object doesn't exist! There's a difference. An object is an instance (in memory) and a variable is a reference to the object. In his case the object does not exist. see: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/254689/difference-between-instance-object

Comment: It's strange talking about "***the***" object in the absence of any object. A *variable* holds (points to/references) a *value*. If a variable holds an object, then the value is an object. If a variable holds the value `undefined`, then the value is `undefined`. If a variable holds the value `undefined`, then it doesn't hold an object (d'uh).

Comment: Ah fair point. It's a primitive value not an object. I will update my answer. Thank you for pointing that out.